# How to make a dependent drop-down be required when there are options available using Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to Django/Python, so apologies in advance. I have a form with a dependent drop-down. Currently, I have it set so that the second drop-down only appears if there are options available in it, otherwise is hidden. What I am having trouble with is that, whenever you choose a primary(Work Area) option that has a secondary(Station) drop-down, you can submit the form without having selected an option from the dependent (secondary) drop-down, which is supposed to be required whenever there are options in it.

How can I modify this so that the dependent drop-down is required whenever it appears?

**models.py**

```
class WorkArea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Station(models.Model):
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="stations")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, help_text="Work Area", related_name="work_area")
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Station", related_name="stations", blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['station_number'].queryset = Station.objects.none()

        if 'work_area' in self.data:
            try:
                work_area_id = int(self.data.get('work_area'))
                self.fields['station_number'].queryset = Station.objects.filter(work_area_id=work_area_id).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['station_number'].queryset = self.instance.work_area.stations.order_by('name')
```

**views.py**

```
def enter_exit_area(request):
    enter_without_exit = None
    exit_without_enter = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Form handling...

def load_stations(request):
    work_area_id = request.GET.get('work_area')
    stations = Station.objects.filter(work_area_id=work_area_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'operations/station_number_dropdown_options.html', {'stations': stations})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', views.enter_exit_area, name='enter_exit_area'),

    path('ajax/load-stations/', views.load_stations, name='ajax_load_stations'),
]
```

**station_number_dropdown_options.html**

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for station in stations %}
<option value="{{ station.pk }}">{{ station.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried adding this to forms.py

```
    def clean(self):
        work_area = self.cleaned_data['work_area']
        station = self.cleaned_data['station_number']

        if work_area in ('3', '4', '5', '6', '1') and station is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must select a station")
        return work_area
```

but I get
`AttributeError: 'WorkArea' object has no attribute 'get'`

How could I fix this error? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your clean method:

```py
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    work_area = cleaned_data['work_area']
    station = cleaned_data['station_number']
    if work_area in ('3', '4', '5', '6', '1') and station is None:
        text = f'You must select a station for work area {work_area}!'
        self.add_error('station_number', text)
```

In the main clean method you shouldn't return anything.
As a rule the generic clean method should be used when you need to depend on multiple values just as you're doing. If you need to clean single values you should use something like:

```py
def clean_work_area(self):
    work_area = self.cleaned_data['work_area']
    if [condition]:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(area)s failed condition!'),
            params={'area': work_area},
        )
    return work_area
```

In which case you should always return the value that you're cleaning.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!!